# Plotting a collection of sine waves

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have the following code:

```
Fs = 1000;
T = 1/Fs;
L = 1000;
t = (0:L-1)*T;
k = 25:1:50;
m = 1:1:25;
```

where `k` and `m` are corresponding. I want to plot the 25 sine waves resulting from:

```
x = m*sin(2*pi*k*t);
```

I thought about doing it using a `for` loop that takes one value from `m` and `k` each time, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: x=m*sin(2*pi**k*t)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add additional information or include corrections.

Comment: I need 25 sine waves and I can plot them one by one then add them together but it takes to long time that's why I wanted make a for loop.

Comment: Please show us the expected result (when you plot it your way).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very basic plotting solution. You will notice that it's very difficult to see what's going on in the plot, so you might want to consider other ways to present this data.

```
function q45532082
Fs = 1000;
T = 1/Fs;
L = 1000;
t = (0:L-1)*T;
k = 26:1:50;
m = 1:1:25;
%% Plotting
assert(numel(m) == numel(k)); % We make sure that the number of elements is the same.
figure(); hold on; % "hold" is needed if you want to see all curves at the same time.
for ind1 = 1:numel(m)
  plot(t,m(ind1)*sin(2*pi*k(ind1)*t));
end
```

This is the result:

[image: The result]

Note that the number of elements in `k` and `m` in your code is different, so I had to change it.

Comment: it should not be like that. K is the frequency and the result supposed to be sine waves starting since 26 Hz to 50 Hz and m is their magnitude.

Comment: I need 25 sine waves and I can plot them one by one then add them together but it takes to long time that's why I wanted make a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using the functionality of [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?s_tid=doc_ta#btzptin) you can also plot all sine waves without a loop:

```
Fs = 1000;
T = 1/Fs;
L = 1000;
t = (0:L-1)*T;
k = 26:1:50;
m = 1:1:25;
x = m.*sin(2.*pi.*bsxfun(@times,t.',k)); %this results in an L*25 matrix, each column is data of one wave
% or, if you have version 2016b or newer:
% x = m.*sin(2.*pi.*t.'*k);
plot(t,x) % plot all sines at ones
```

and as [@Dev-iL noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45532511/2627163), I also had to change `k`.

The result with `L = 1000` is too crowded, so I plot it here with `L = 50`:

[image]

Comment: I tried and the result Error in ==> a4 at 7        K is the frequency and the result supposed to be sine waves starting since 26 Hz to 50 Hz and m is their magnitude

Comment: I need 25 sine waves and I can plot them one by one then add them together but it takes to long time that's why I wanted make a for loop.

Comment: @Mohammad the code above does exactly that. It plots 25 sine waves with different` and `k`. The is no need in a `for` loop to plot them all together. As for the error, see the comment in the code relating your version of Matlab.

Comment: thanks a lot, my matlab version is old (2010) thats why I am trying to make a for loop

Comment: you can still use `bsxfun`, you don't need the `for` loop

Comment: Error in ==> a4 at 7
x =
m.*sin(2.*pi.*bsxfun(@times,t.',k));
%this results in an L*25 matrix,
each column is data of one wave

Comment: That can't be all the errors text, it only says _where_ the error is, but not _what_ is the error. (could be something like _"Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other"_), also, if you wrote a function that called **`a4`**, please provide it in the question.

Comment: a4 just is the name that I have saved my script

Comment: Fine, but still you need to copy the content of the error... alternatively, try to just copy and paste the code above as is in a clear script file, then type `clear` in the command window, and run it. That shouldn't result in any error (and if it is, try to restart Matlab).

Comment: I have done all and there is no clear explanation in error. It just says error in line 7

Comment: Well, sorry, I have no idea what this could be, but if the other answer does not result in any errors, use it. It will give you the exact same result.